# Handling blank values of attributes in xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I am printing values of XML tags and attributes present in them. If the value of any attribute or tag is blank then I am trying to print `None`. I am able to do it for empty tags but code is not printing `None` if there is any blank attribute value.

XML (a.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number sep = "help" dep = "paraug" note = "zempu">QWZ5671</item_number>
         <line cap = "delp" des = "" fote = "cat"></line>
         <cool_number>QWZ5671</cool_number>
         <price>39.5</price>
         <price></price>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

code:

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import defaultdict

root_1 = etree.parse('a.xml').getroot()
d1= []

for node in root_1.findall('.//catalog_item'):
    item = defaultdict(list)
    for x in node.iter():
        # iterate over the items
        for k, v in x.attrib.items():
            item[k].append(v)
        if x.attrib is None:
          item[x.attrib].append('None')
        if x.text is None:
          item[x.tag].append('None')
        elif x.text.strip():
            item[x.tag].append(x.text.strip())

    d1.append(dict(item))
print(d1)
```

Current output: attribute value of `des` is blank in XML hence it is coming here blank but line tag is coming up with `None`

```
[{'gender': ["Men's"], 'sep': ['help'], 'dep': ['paraug'], 'note': ['zempu'], 'item_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'cap': ['delp'], 'des': [''], 'fote': ['cat'], 'line': ['None'], 'cool_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'price': ['39.5', 'None']}]
```

Expected output: if the attribute value is blank then `None` should come for that also as shown for `des` here

````
[{'gender': ["Men's"], 'sep': ['help'], 'dep': ['paraug'], 'note': ['zempu'], 'item_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'cap': ['delp'], 'des': ['None'], 'fote': ['cat'], 'line': ['None'], 'cool_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'price': ['39.5', 'None']}]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is with the way you are currently testing for empty attributes:

```
if x.attrib is None:
```

this checks whether a node has any attributes at all (x.attrib is the dict holding all of a nodes attributes). you could fix it by replacing this

```
for k, v in x.attrib.items():
    item[k].append(v)
if x.attrib is None:
  item[x.attrib].append('None')
```

by this

```
for k, v in x.attrib.items():
    item[k].append(v if v else None)  # use str(None) if you really need a string
```

which will produce the following output:

```
[{'note': ['zempu'], 'item_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'cool_number': ['QWZ5671'], 'cap': ['delp'], 'des': [None], 'sep': ['help'], 'fote': ['cat'], 'dep': ['paraug'], 'line': ['None'], 'price': ['39.5', 'None'], 'gender': ["Men's"]}]
```